# IIS Directory Browing

Tags: iis, directory, iis-6

If I enable directory browsing in IIS it displays folder contents to user. Is there any way of controlling the way it shows the list. For example, I don't want to show full physical path of the folder. Is it possible to achieve? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Directory browsing will not show the full path in the browser. Where do you see the full path?

[image]

Comment: The path on the top localhost-/music/. Can I configure it to not to display this?